# mod_proxy_html configuration - truncation issues

Tags: apache, proxy, redhat, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-html

I've looked around as much as I can, and I've hit the point where I'm completely stumped.

I'm running a RedHat server with Apache on top, which I'm using as a proxy to sit between the outside world and two other application servers, with completely different bases (one IIS, one Linux).

Both of these servers have correct internal network URLs, that the applications residing on them understand. The apps (DotNetNuke and WordPress derived) both generate HTML 5 pages, which contain the correct / appropriate markup, and render correctly outside of the proxy (i.e. on the internal network).

When passing these pages through the proxy however, the result seems to be missing characters at the end of CSS and JavaScript files.

So (in practice), JavaScript code like this:

```
... {return f})})(window);
```

or CSS like this:

```
...
background-position:center left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

...turns into code like this:

```
... {return f})})(window
```

or like this:

```
...
background-position:center left;
background-repeat:no-re
```

The proxy setup is using the mod_proxy and mod_proxy_html Apache modules - and I'm fairly certain that the problem I'm encountering is to do with the configuration of mod_proxy_html, which currently looks like this:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLBufSize  102400
ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLStripComments Off
ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>"
ProxyHTMLMeta Off
#ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
#LogLevel Debug

<Location /xxxxx>
        ProxyPass               http://www.example.com
        ProxyPassReverse        http://www.example.com
        ProxyHTMLURLMap         http://www.example.com /xxxxx
        ProxyHTMLURLMap         / /xxxxx/
</Location>

<Location />
        ProxyPass               http://10.11.0.51/
        ProxyPassReverse        http://10.11.0.51/
</Location>
```

Going through the Apache docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy_html.html - doesn't give any immediate clues however.

Has anyone come across the same issue? Or is there something quick that I'm missing?

Any help would be gratefully received!

**Updated:**

Ultimately, the problem appeared to be the default behaviour of mod_proxy_html in parsing all content as UTF-8 encoded (when some of the content wasn't - which couldn't be amended, despite best efforts).

To this end, after a bit of work, mod_substitute was used instead (just parsing text as text, ignoring file encoding) alongside a cache solution to speed up load times.

Shame mod_proxy_html didn't work for this project - but a way was found to do it in the end!

Comment: Strange update to this - I've noticed that the code returned to any browser in Linux (e.g. Chrome, Chromium, Firefox) is truncated, but in a Windows 7 environment, it's not truncated in all browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari all return truncated files - Firefox returns the full file).Could it be anything to do with the way the browser is making the request?

Comment: Problem solved in the end (by way of not using this module to achieve the end result) - but I can't close the question, so please don't answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem IS related to a bug within mod_proxy_html (s. http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/PATCH-mod-xml2enc-eats-end-of-file-td5001104.html)

I was able to verify the described behavior (see apache´s error log with loglevel *debug*) and the patch works for me - although its approach is not a perfect solution.

Versions:
mod_xml2enc (1.0.4)
libxml2 (2.7.6-0.9.1)

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>"
```

to

```
ProxyHTMLDocType "<!DOCTYPE html>" XML
```

Be aware of

```
ProxyHTMLStripComments Off
```

that does not work for all comments. Haven't figured out a solution for this one yet.

Comment: That's interesting - if I understand it correctly, that forces mod_proxy_html to believe its parsing XML as opposed to HTML?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Personally i have abandoned mod_proxy_html, its just not worth the pain, because its re-parsing the page, then generates a new page. Now I am using mod_substitute, to do plain text search and replace of page output, simpler, faster, do what I want it to do.